# Nested While Loop PHP

Tags: php, loops, mysqli

I need help with loop through MySQL data.

I have stock table as below.

[image]

What I would like to do is do an select statement which would get all the rows from stock table, if it has "numberassigned_vnr" more than 1, loop through that and show that as separate row.

I need help with writing select statement which would loop through the table and show result and if has "numberassigned_vnr" more than one, loop through and print the result to that number of times.

So I should see something like this.

```
1   27  300  Black
1   27  300  Black
1   27  300  Black
7   29  315  Black
7   29  315  Black
2   28  315  Black
3   29  315  Black
......
.....
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you should read the fine manual: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: You are asking for the duplicate records. .
I think you should do the required looping with php only

Comment: Yes duplicating records. The 2nd loop would look for the "numberassigned_vnr" value and if it;s more than one; it should duplicate that records to number of that times.

Comment: @MuhammadIkram so you want to duplicate the records at the level of mysql, or to duplicate them in php?

Answer (score 0):

PHP :

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)){

    $numberassigned_vnr=$row['numberassigned_vnr'];

    for($i=1;$i<=$numberassigned_vnr;$i++){

        echo "your coloumns here like $row[coloumn1] $row[coloumn2]...";

    }

}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can Do like this

```
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if (!empty($result)) {
        foreach ($result as $data) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < $data->numberassigned_vnr; $i++) {
                echo "$data->id_vnr $data->idstk_vnr $data->width_vnr $data->color_vnr ";
            }
        }
    }
```

I hting it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

if you are asking about printing the row multiple times according to 'numberassigned_vnr', here is the solution:

```
// $conn = your db connection

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM your_table");

if(!empty($result)) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

        for($i=0; $i < $row['numberassigned_vnr']; $i++){
            echo $row['id_vnr']." ".$row['idstk_vnr']." ".$row['width_vnr']." ".$row['color_vnr'];
        }
    }

    // Free result set
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) with the `WHERE` handle on the `MySQL` statement, getting all result where `numberassigned_vnr > 1`.

Something as following:

```
$db = new PDO("...");
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM stock_table WHERE numberassigned_vnr > :nrassigned");
$statement->execute(array(':nrassigned' => 1));    
while ($row = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    var_dump($row); // var_dump complete row
    echo $row['id_vnr'] . " " . $row['idstk_vnr'] . " " . $row['width_vnr'] . " " . $row['color_vnr'];
}
```